# Cannot create an avd

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I have a windows 7 machine.I am trying to create a new AVD in android studio.I have all the options set accordingly.but still the ok button does not become valid.please help

Comment: maybe you can show a picture of what your facing.

Comment: A screenshot of your problem would be more expressive

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have both selected target and device installed on your Android SDK, and make sure you selected a valid Skin for that device.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any error shown for this device? On my screenshot I have no CPU/ABI installed for the given Api-Level 19 and the option is greyed. In this case you have to install an ARM for the chosen api level in the android sdk manager.

[image: AVD Device Configuration screen of the avd manager]